# Recycler space ItemDecoration keeps increasing during scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my first stack overflow question. I have been trying to find a solution to this problem on stack overflow in the last a few hours and I couldn't find anything.

The app (or a specific activity) I am creating here is very simple, basically a vertical recycler containing TextView and RecyclerView, something like:

Vertical RecyclerView

--- TextView (title)

--- Horizontal RecyclerView (card view)

--- TextView (title)

--- Horizontal RecyclerView (card view)

... (more goes here)

--- TextView (title)

--- Horizontal RecyclerView (card view)

(End of Vertical RecyclerView)

Everything works correctly, except when I start scrolling the vertical recycler (up and down), the first and last two horizontal RecyclerView's space item decoration (shown below) keeps increasing. I have my guess where the problem might be, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Horizontal Recycler Adapter (which is very standard)

```
 public class HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
private Context mContext;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of mDataset)
public HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter(Context myContext, ArrayList myDataset) {
    this.mContext = myContext;
    this.mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                   int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.view_image, parent, false);
    // Goes here: set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your mDataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element

    String mDrawableName = mDataset.get(position);
    int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
    holder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(resID);
}

// Return the size of your mDataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}
```

Space Item Decoration

```
class HorizantalSpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private final int mHorizantalSpaceWidth;

public HorizantalSpaceItemDecoration(int horizantalItemSpace) {
    mHorizantalSpaceWidth = horizantalItemSpace;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                           RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.right = mHorizantalSpaceWidth;
}
```

Vertical Recycler Adapter:

```
public class VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> mHeaderList;
private ArrayList<String> mSportList;
private ArrayList<Boolean> mSpaceItemDecorationFlagList;
private Context context;

public static final int HORIZANTAL_ITEM_SPACE = 30;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView textView;
    public CardView cardView;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        textView = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of mHeaderList)
public VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    String[] headers = res.getStringArray(R.array.header_home);
    mHeaderList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(headers));
    String[] sports = res.getStringArray(R.array.sports);
    mSportList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sports));
    mSpaceItemDecorationFlagList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for(int i = 0; i < mHeaderList.size(); i++){
        mSpaceItemDecorationFlagList.add(false);
    }
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
    // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
    return position % 2 * 2;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                 int viewType) {
    // Create a new view depends on view type
    // 0: Text View (Header)
    // 1: Recycler View (Category Explorer)
    View newView;

    if(viewType == 0) {
        newView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_text, parent, false);
    }else{
        newView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_recycler, parent, false);
    }
    // Goes here: set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(newView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // - get element from your mHeaderList at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    if(position % 2 == 0)
    {
        String header = mHeaderList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(header);
    }else{
        // ??????????????
        // Problem might be holder.recyclerView not reset properly?

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager popularLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter(context, mSportList);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(popularLayoutManager);
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //add Space ItemDecoration
        holder.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizantalSpaceItemDecoration(HORIZANTAL_ITEM_SPACE));
        holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    }
}

// Return the size of your mHeaderList (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mHeaderList.size();
}
```

In each horizontal recycler, I am trying to add 30 dp space between each image/item, but during scrolling, the first horizontal and last two horizontal recycler views kept increasing. (30, then 60 then 90 I am guessing?)

my guess is in onBindViewHolder(), my holder's recycler view is not reset properly, and its rect.right keeps getting updated to a new value (old + 30). But this is purely my guessing. Could anyone else please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you reach the last item, you are adding an itemdecorator, and scroll at the same time, what makes the holder try to bind another element, probably another itemDecoration. Check if you need another condition inside your onBindViewHolder() method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the item decorator is being added **every time** data is being binded to a viewholder. While the ones that were added earlier are never being removed.

A check can be done to prevent this, or we can remove the existing ones. But it is better to only declare and add the decorator once, that is, when creating the viewholder.

So to solve this:

**In class `VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter`:**

- Currently you are adding the item decoration in the `onBindViewHolder` method. Which gets called every time a holder is rerendered (happens when scrolling), thus we need to remove it from here.
- Then go to the `onCreateViewHolder` method and add the decoration to the viewholder there.
- *Note that you need to check if the `viewType == 1` in your situation, as otherwise it will result in a NullPointer.*

So your resulting `onCreateViewHolder` method could look as follows:

```
// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                 int viewType) {
    // Create a new view depends on view type
    // 0: Text View (Header)
    // 1: Recycler View (Category Explorer)
    View newView;

    if (viewType == 0) {
        newView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_text, parent, false);
    } else {
        newView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.view_recycler, parent, false);
    }
    // Goes here: set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(newView);
    if (viewType == 1) {
        // Adding the itemDecorator here
        viewHolder.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizantalSpaceItemDecoration(HORIZANTAL_ITEM_SPACE));
    }
    return viewHolder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, answered my question. Great help.

Comment: Your welcome, please mark the answer as the solution if this fully solved the problem @user8048493

Comment: Thanks it help me too.

Answer (score 8):

For those who are facing this issue, it could be because you are adding the item decoration view every time there is an update to your data (which is bad). But as a quick fix, you could check if the recycler view has any item decorators added and if not you could add yours. Add this in your Activity or fragment file where you initialize adapter

```
if (your_recycler_view.itemDecorationCount < 1) {
    your_recycler_view.addItemDecoration(HorizantalSpaceItemDecoration())
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much I had a similar issue with horizontal recyclerview, now it's fixed by you solution